# Filter by attribute in Rails by using Filterific gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I have User model which has `role` (String) attribute. I want to filter my Users by this role attribute.

For filtering I'm using [filterific](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/) gem.
Here is my `index` action:

```ruby
 def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
        User,
        params[:filterrific],
        select_options: {
            with_role: User.options_for_select
        },

    ) or return
    @users = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])
  end
```

where `options_for_select` method is defined:

```ruby
# user.rb
def self.options_for_select
    order('LOWER(role)').map { |e| [e.role, e.id] }
end
```

and in my view:

```ruby
<%= f.select(
      :with_role,
      @filterrific.select_options[:with_role],
      { include_blank: '- Any -' }
) %>
```

and I have a scope in my user.rb:

```ruby
scope :with_role, lambda { |roles|
        where(role: [*roles])
      }
```

I have only five roles, but in my select each role appears many times, so I don't know how to return unique roles in `options_for_select` method.

Secondly, `options_for_select` returns id's of user as a value in each option tag, but I want it to return role itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `options_for_select` on the `User` model. So it pulls in every user record in your database and its associated role entry, along with the user id.

Try the following instead of `User.options_for_select` in the controller:

```
select_options: {
  with_role: ['Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3']
},
```